# How can I swap the position of shipping and tax on the invoice?

Tags: invoice

I wish to swap the position of tax and shipping on the invoice.

How can I go about to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the Magento Configuration.
Go to **System**->**Configuration**->**Sales**->**Checkout Total Sort Order**.
Change the order as you want.

Comment: Thank you, however it does not seem to be changing. No matter the values in the boxes?